# Regard Q(rational numbers) as a metric space, with d(p, q) = |p − q|. Let E be the set of all p ∈ Q such that $2 < p^2 < 3$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

So the problem:Regard Q(rational numbers) as a metric space, with d(p, q) = |p − q|. Let E be the set of all p ∈ Q such that $2 < p^2 < 3$.
I want to show, that set $E$ is closed.

I did with the help of arguments, that $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ cannot be represented as rational numbers. Then we can see, that all limit points of interval E = Q union [($-\sqrt 3$;$-\sqrt 2$) union ($\sqrt 2$;$\sqrt 3$)]
lie in set E. So set is closed.

I just want to ask about specific solution:[image]

But I can't get the alternative approach(which is more rigourous than mine)
What does $\sigma$ mean? Why do we need $y = x + h$? Can you explain me this solution?

P.S And is it good, that I used less rigurous proof(but I understood the idea well)? Or should I try to dive in mathematical details?

Comment: Your argument is not very clear for me. Perhaps you should add more details. In particular I believe you have some typos in how you define E as the union of Q and some open intervals. Wouldn't this prove that E is open? The proof which is written shows that the complement of E is open, from which it follows that E is closed. To show that E is open they show that each point is an interior point. The $\delta $ is the size of the ball (depending on the point $x $) which is contained in Q\E.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the explanation!
Can I ask you how the author of proof above chose the points of ball sigma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will continue the explanation here, since it will be difficult to read in the hint. Your question is: how the author chooses the $\delta$ (note, this is actually a delta, not a sigma! Though they look very similar, delta is often used to denote small numbers).

I will consider the $0\neq x < \sqrt{2}$ case, as in the proof. We aim to show that $x \in Q\setminus E$ has a neighborhood around it which is entirely contained in $Q\setminus E$. That is, does there exist a $\delta$ sufficiently small so that any rational number $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is also in $Q\setminus E$?

We can construct the $\delta$ as follows: note that $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ satisfies

$$y^2 < (x+\delta)^2 \leq x^2 + 2|x|\delta + \delta^2.$$

So, if we want $y\in Q\setminus E$, then we want $x^2+2|x|\delta+\delta^2<2$. A simple way to see what $\delta$ will work is to simply plug in expressions ad hoc. Also, note that the $\delta$ which I think about may be different for the $2|x|\delta$ term and the $\delta^2$ term. To emphasize this, I will use $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, respectively, and then set $\delta = \min \{\delta_1,\delta_2\}.$  This is very typical in analysis and explains why $\delta$ in proofs is often expressed as a minimum of several values.

First, I want to use the fact that $2-x^2>0$, so perhaps I guess $\delta_1= \frac{2-x^2}{2|x|}$ to kill off the middle term. Then

$$x^2+2|x|\delta_1+\delta_2^2 = x^2 + (2-x^2) + \delta_2^2 = 2+\delta_2^2.$$

We see that the problem here is that I have overshot my target since $2+\delta_2^2$ is larger than $2$.  However, we can simply take a slightly smaller number (as the authors do) $\delta_1 = \frac{2-x^2}{3|x|}$ so that I get

$$x^2+2|x|\delta_1 +\delta_2^2 = \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{4}{3} + \delta_2^2.$$

Now, I want this expression to be equal to $2$, so I can solve

$$\frac{1}{3} x^2 + \frac{4}{3} +\delta_2^2 = 2$$

for $\delta_2$:

$$\delta_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2-x^2}{3}}.$$

So, taking $\delta = \min \{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ recovers exactly the $\delta$-ball which is used in the proof above.

Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Thank you very much! The logic is completely clear!
Need to work hard, to handle such exercises without help:)

Comment: You're welcome! The intuition will come in time, just keep practicing! Good luck!

Comment: And if you don't mind one more (soft)question about practice in math(real analysis):

For example, I spent on problem 1 hour and didn't solve it. What should i do in this case:
1)Try to solve it further(when to stop)
2)Look at the answer and go step-by-step through solution
3)Try to solve it next day?

I need to develope right strategy of learning.
Your advices will be helpfull for me:)

Comment: If you are stuck on a problem try to identify the gap. Your original question shows that you had issues with definitions. Try to be critical with these things. Make an effort to understand the definitions of closed sets and what exactly you must do to prove or disprove something is closed.  Look at problems in books to build tools and intuition. I do think there is value to waiting a day to try a problem fresh. After a few days, you can talk to a professor or ask here! Also, 1 hr feels long now, but with practice you will be able to attack problems much longer w/o feeling tired/discouraged!

Comment: Thank you for your advice:)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!  By the way, I just noticed your P.S. in the question. I believe the answer is overwhelmingly yes to write details.  At this stage in your experience, it is very important to write all details otherwise you will not know whether or not there could be a gap in your proof.